# Перевод числа в указанную систему счисления

Tags: c, функции, циклы, системы-счисления

Написал функцию которая переводит число в систему счисления и функцию возведения целого числа в степень. Не понимаю почему получается неправильный результат.
Например: число 100, сис.счисления 8, результат 64 Вместо 144.

```
void to_base_n(int n, int base) // переводит число в основание системы счисления
{
    int result, i, modulo, number;

    result = 0;
    number = n;

    for (i = 0; n; i++)
    {
        modulo = n % base;
        result += (power(base, i) * modulo);    // 8^0 * (245 % 10) + 8^1 (24 % 10) ... 
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("\nChislo %d v sisteme schisleniya %d = %d;\n", number, base, result);

    return;
}
int power(int n, int pow)   // функция возведения числа в степерь
{
    int power, i;

    power = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= pow; i++)
        power *= n;

    return power;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. И в правильном ли направлении я ищу решение?

Comment: Судя по результату вы перепутали входную и выходную системы счисления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно из условия, что вам нужно.
Перевод из десятичной системы счисления в любую другую, или наоборот. Ибо алгоритмы разные.

Собственно функция перевода десятичного числа в другую систему счисления(для 16 ричной такой вариант уже не подойдет) выглядит так:

```
void to_base_n(int n, int base) 
{
    int result, i, modulo, number;
    result = 0;
    number = n;

    for (i = 0; n; i++)
    {
        modulo = n % base;
        result += (power(10, i) * modulo);     
        n /= base;
    }
    printf("\nChislo %d v sisteme schisleniya %d = %d;\n", number, base, result);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Например: число 100, сис.счисления 8, результат 64 Вместо 144.

Считаем:

- 100(8) == 64(10)
- 40(8) == 32(10)
- 4(8) ==  4(10)
- 64 + 32 + 4 == 100(10)

И что Вам не нравится?